# simplifying the quotient of two radical expressions

Tags: radicals

How do we find $p$ and $q$ so that $$\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{\sqrt{2}-1}=p+q\sqrt{2}\,?$$

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  The question asks to find the values of p and q.  I have the answer key, which states that p = 4 and q = 3, but do not know how to arrive at that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply numerator and denominator by the "conjugate" $\sqrt{2}+1$, giving $$\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{\sqrt{2}-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}+2}{1}=4+3\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. (you can upvote my answer and select it as the answer to your question to show thanks, too.) this trick of multiplying by the conjugate is very useful when you're doing arithmetic with radicals.